# Taking appropriate limits

Tags: limits

$$E=\dfrac{h\nu}{e^x-1}$$

where $$x=h\nu /(kT)$$

$h$ and $k$ are constants, $\nu$ is frequency and $T$ is temperature

Show by taking appropriate limits that at high temperatures $E=kT$. I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I know that as temperature increases $x$ becomes smaller. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{hv}{e^{hv/(kT)}-1}=\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{\frac{hv}{kT}kT}{e^{hv/(kT)}-1}$$

Now Put $$\frac{hv}{kT}=x$$

as $T\to\infty$ , $x\to0$

> Use$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{e^{x}-1}=1$$

$$E=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xkT}{e^{x}-1}=1\times kT$$

$$\implies E=kT$$

Comment: You may want to add a L'Hopital's step in there. That's what had me confused when I first read your answer. Thanks, that helped a lot.

Comment: I used it to get rid of the x on top and the -1 on bottom

Comment: I don't know that standard limit so I'm going to use L'Hopitals, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't really talk about the limit since the energy becomes infinite when $T$ goes to $\infty$.

But at high temperature you have $x$ very small, and thus $e^x-1=x+o(x²)$, or $e^{\frac{1}{T}}-1=\frac{1}{T}+o(\frac{1}{T²})$.

From here you can deduce fairly easily that:

$E=h\nu \dfrac{1}{e^x-1}=\dfrac{h\nu}{x}+o(x)$

Replacing $x=\dfrac{h\nu}{kT}$

$E\simeq kT$